# Select lines in Eclipse by clicking in the margin

Tags: eclipse, mouse, eclipse-cdt, margins

I'm using Eclipse CDT (Kepler) on Windows.

I'd like to select lines by clicking the mouse in the margins of the editor.

In many Windows editors (Visual Studio, Source Insight, Notepad++, Microsoft Word) if you move the mouse to the left margin of the editor, the mouse pointer (which usually points leftward) points rightward.  If you click once, that selects the line; if you click and drag, it selects multiple lines.

Is there a way to configure Eclipse to behave the same way?

I find that in my left margin, the mouse pointer always points to the left.  Clicking once has no effect.  Click-dragging works only sometimes, which is infuriating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 distinct left-margin areas in the Eclipse editors (at least some of the editors, including the Java editor), the *overview ruler* and the *vertical ruler*.

[image]

Click+drag line selecting has to be done in the *vertical ruler* area, not the *overview ruler*.

To select just one line, you can also triple-click *anywhere* on that line.

**Update:**
If you have *Code Folding* enabled, those indicators are shown in the *vertical ruler* when you hover the pointer over an area that can be folded. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is *almost* correct, for me.  I have what seems to be *three* rulers.  In addition to the overview ruler and the vertical ruler, there's an additional place that makes a vertical line appear on the margin.  

  Let's say I have the mouse pointer over text (looks like a vertical bar); if I move it gradually leftwards, it will change to a pointer and a black vertical line will appear; if I move it more, the line disappears--that must be when I'm over the vertical ruler; if I move it more, it must get to the overview ruler.  

  Can I change the pointer so it points up and right?

Comment: That sounds like you have *Folding* enabled. I updated my answer to show an example of that.